# Select only rows by join tables max value

Tags: sql, join

I want to select only the row which has max b.enddate for u.classno, u.userno. But it doesn't work.

```
select u.classno, u.userno, b.enddate
from libUser u
join book b on b.id = u.bookid
group by u.classno, u.userno
having b.enddate=max(b.enddate) //doesn't works
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whats wrong with:

```
select u.classno, u.userno, MAX(b.enddate)
from libUser u
join book b on b.id = u.bookid
group by u.classno, u.userno
```

Comment: This answer is **perfectly correct**. But in case someone needs this:
This approach isn't always reliable as it will pick **any** row value for non-groped columns viz. `u.classno` and `u.userno` **if they are not included in the group by clause** the value may not be from the same row as `MAX(b.enddate)` is picked from. Usually, it is the first row from each `group` that may change depending on the `order by` clause.
I verified this on `MySQL` before writing here. MS-SQL does not allow such query at all. Don't know about other RDBMS.

Answer (score 61):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html) is an excellent article in the official MySQL documentation, but only standard SQL is used there, so it can be applied to whatever RDBMS you are using.

> ### The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column
>
> Task: For each article, find the dealer or dealers with the most
>   expensive price.
>
> This problem can be solved with a subquery like this one:
>
> ```
> SELECT article, dealer, price
> FROM   shop s1
> WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
>               FROM shop s2
>               WHERE s1.article = s2.article);
> ```
>
> The preceding example uses a correlated subquery, which can be
>   inefficient (see Section 13.2.10.7, “Correlated Subqueries”). Other
>   possibilities for solving the problem are to use an uncorrelated
>   subquery in the FROM clause or a LEFT JOIN.
>
> **Uncorrelated subquery:**
>
> ```
> SELECT s1.article, dealer, s1.price
> FROM shop s1
> JOIN (
>   SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
>   FROM shop
>   GROUP BY article) AS s2
>   ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price = s2.price;
> ```
>
> **LEFT JOIN:**
>
> ```
> SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
> FROM shop s1
> LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price
> WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
> ```
>
> The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when s1.price is at its maximum
>   value, there is no s2.price with a greater value and the s2 rows
>   values will be NULL.

Comment: Wow, you had that answer prepared beforehand didn't you :P

Comment: Nothing wrong with any of it, I was just impressed by the speed.

Comment: so, which one is faster?

Comment: @thenaglecode It depends on the data you have, but most of the time the uncorrelated subquery is the fastest for me (in MySQL that is, it also depends on the DBMS you're using).

Comment: Using uncorrelated subquery in my MySql app with great results.