# table join with priority attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basicly, I have a table with a priority attribute and a value, like

```
TargetID Priority_Column (int)   Value_column
1                  1             "value 1"
1                  2             "value 2"
1                  5             "value 5
2                  1             "value 1"
2                  2             "value 2"
```

I want to join another table with this table,

```
 ID  Name
 1   "name 1"
 2   "name 2"
```

but only using the row with highest priority.

The result would be like

```
TargetID Priority_Column (int)  Name        Value_column
1                  5            "name 1"    "value 5"
2                  2            "name 2"    "value 2"
```

I can of course use a high-level language like python to compute highest priority row for each ID.

But that looks inefficient, is there a way to directly do this in sql?

Comment: can u put a example resultset ? Right now it's not very clear what result You want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using `outer apply`:

```
select t2.*, t1.*
from table2 t2 outer apply
     (select top 1 t1.*
      from table1 t1
      where t2.id = t1.targetid
      order by priority desc
     ) t1;
```

I should note that in SQL Server, this is often the most efficient method.  It will take good advantage of an index on `table1(targetid, priority)`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options for this.  Here's one using `row_number`:

```
select *
from anothertable a join (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by targetid order by priority desc) rn
    from yourtable) t on a.id = t.targetid and t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand Your question correctly - You want a "Max By" from the second table..

here's a sample of that
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18694271/444149

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, you could write an sql query where you would get the max() priority or min() priority accordingly.

In your case, with max priority as a required result the query should be:

```
select a.TargetID, a.[Value_column], b.ID, b.Name
from TableA a
     join TableB b
        on a.TargetID = b.ID
where a.Priority_Column = (select max(z.Priority_Column) from TableA z 
                          and z.ID = a.TargetID)
```

... edited to reflect your resultset

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  TargetID,
        Priority_Column,
        Name,
        Value_Column
FROM    (SELECT t1.TargetID,
                t1.Priority_Column,
                t2.Name,
                t1.Value_column,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TargetID ORDER BY Priority_Column DESC) Rn
         FROM   Table1 t1
                JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.TargetId = t2.ID
        ) t
WHERE   Rn = 1
```