# How to combine multiple records in one in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a SQL table that looks something like this:

| OP | ID | First name | Last name | Phone number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I | 123 | John | Smith | 888-555 |
| U | 123 |  |  | 777-555 |

I have to combine this rows through select query into something like this:

| ID | First name | Last name | Phone number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | John | Smith | 777-555 |

I have trouble writing query because my only idea is with MAX, but sometimes is field from U row lesser than the one in I row and I need to check every column.

What I tried:

```
Select ID,
max('First name') as 'First name',
max('Last name') as 'Last name',
max('Phone number') as 'Phone number'
from table
group by ID
```

Please help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a priority, with `U` first then `I`.  One method is to use `coalesce()` with conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       coalesce(max(case when OP = 'I' then first_name end),
                max(first_name)
               ) as first_name,
       coalesce(max(case when OP = 'I' then last_name end),
                max(last_name)
               ) as last_name,
       coalesce(max(case when OP = 'I' then phone_number end),
                max(phone_number)
               ) as phone_number
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Coalesce returns first not-null value? And I have phone number values that are both not-null...

Comment: @robotic_arm13 . . . I don't understand your comment.  You understand `coalesce()`.  The first argument is conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `JOIN` keyword to join the two tables together with the max values included.

Here's a link to reference the code you're looking for: [Select only rows by join tables max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694094/select-only-rows-by-join-tables-max-value/18694271)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an autoreferenced JOIN to search the not null rows and OP = I, to not depends of a MAX

```
SELECT a.OP, a.ID,
COALESCE(a.'First name',b.'First name'),
COALESCE(a.'Last name',b.'Last name'),
'Phone number'
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table WHERE OP = 'I' AND and 'First name' IS NOT NULL AND 'Last name' IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1) b ON b.ID = a.ID;
```